# Is it necessary to configure a managed switch?

Tags: networking, internet, switch

I have a TP Link SG2210P which is a managed switch. Basically, i want to extend internet to my entire house via Access points. I had this switch. Connected the router to the switch, connected all the ethernet ports coming from my APs and started it.

Now, the problem is i am not getting the internet access through the switch to my devices. I have reset the config to defaults, nothing seemed to work. ping shows "Request timed out".

Sometimes, it gets internet and ping shows the data receiving. But after few seconds, it disconnects and never connects again.

I am a newbie in the networking industry and want some help regarding the above issue.

EDIT: 
Talking about my setup, i have a TP Link Archer C1200, with a TP Link Switch SG2210P (PoE) with four access points of TP Link EAP225 (PoE). The router is receiving the internet perfectly fine. The switch is connected to router with a CAT5 ethernet cable and all the 4 ethernet cables(CAT6) coming from AP's are connected to the switch.

The switch has not been configured. Its in the default configuration.

The scenario is i receive internet access for about 5 minutes and it disconnects and never connects back again. Also directly connected my laptop to the switch and tried, got the same result.

Any idea what could be the problem in my setup ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
The issue was resolved. The solution was to assign the IP to the switch by the router. By default, the switch was static but changing the setting to DHCP, resolved the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Super User! Managed switches, in their default configuration, _should_ work out of the box. Configuration is usually done for more advanced needs, like different VLANs, QoS, etc. Can you edit your question and share a bit more info about your setup? Looks like the problem is not the switch _per se_.

Comment: @MrShunz Thank you for the reply. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Even in a small network like this, you can have a lot of problems. Below is a number of things I would check at least if I would encounter such problems.

Is the switch as you expect it to be; do we have permanent layer2-connection over the switch. Connect a pc/laptop via ethernet to the switch. Do you get an IP address? (if so: DHCP on your Internet router works and you have layer 2 and 3 connection with your Internet router. Let it run for a while, and check if after 5 minutes (or your time-out as described in the question) you still have Internet access from your laptop. If that is the case: your switch is OK and your Internet-router is ok.

Do the lights on the APs go out? In that case, you must probably configure some PoE stuff on your switch.

Next step is your access points. Those TP-link EAP's are quite complicated.  To manage them, you will probably need the EAP controller software/cloud access. I would suggest that the problem lies there, but you should be able to see the whole configuration in your cloud-controller.

How is DHCP done? centrally? if not: look at your IP plan to prevent duplicate addresses..

Comment: Thanks for reply sir. When i connect the laptop to the switch through an ethernet cable and i do an 'ipconfig', i get the IP address of the switch. (This is when, the switch is not connected to the router. But when i connect the laptop to the switch which is connected to the router, an IP address is assigned like 192.168.0.149) Talking about the AP's, the lights don't go off, they are green. Also i have configured the AP's via the controller software provided by TP Link and all have the same SSID. I don't really know about DHCP on the router. Can you help me with this ?